# Blender 2.8 freezes when adding new geometry to an exisitng file

Tags: mesh, geometry

I have been having an issue in Blender 2.8, whereby I'm working just fine, and then at one point when I add new geometry (simple shapes like the sphere), Blender freezes.
This hasn't happened before, I am not importing models from anywhere, just adding new meshes and moving them around.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange. The Please add more information, like the polycount of your existing scene and maybe a [screenshot](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1081/23985).